# RxJava - Combining multiple/different web service calls

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm working with the Basecamp api to return and display to do lists. Here's a sample of what I'm doing at the moment:

```
bcxClient
  .fetchToDoLists()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Action1<List<BcxToDoList>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(List<BcxToDoList> bcxToDoLists) {

      for( final BcxToDoList toDoList : bcxToDoLists ) {
        bcxClient
          .fetchToDos( toDoList.bucket.id )
          .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io() )
          .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() )
          .subscribe( new Action1<List<BcxToDo>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<BcxToDo> bcxToDos) {
              for( BcxToDo toDo : bcxToDos ) {
                toDoList.toDos.add( toDo );
              }
            }
          }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable throwable) {
              throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
          });
      }

      mLoremTextView.setText(bcxToDoLists.get(0).name);
    }

  }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
      throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
  });
```

`fetchToDoLists` and `fetchToDos` are Retrofit web service calls that return the `BcxToDoList` and `BcxToDos` Observables.

In the subscription to `fetchToDoLists` I loop through each BcxToDoList, call `fetchToDos` and attach my BcxToDo objects to the original list.

As you can see, it's a little verbose. I could just separate this into two statements to make it a little bit more readable. But, that's not very Rx. Is there a different way to do this in RxJava and improve its readability?

I could use lambdas to make this compact, but at this stage I'm more interested in what features in RxJava I could take advantage of.

Comment: I'm really new to this so I can't really help, but I figured I'd ask - does this help you? https://github.com/vyshane/rex-weather/blob/master/app/src/main/java/mu/node/rexweather/app/Services/WeatherService.java

Comment: Seeing the how the flatMaps worked helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not "break the chain" in your RxJava calls, hence you will need flatMap to chain them. Also Observable.from() lets you split List of elements into separate Observables. Next, you can use toList to get elements back into list. Here's an example :

```
bcxClient
        .fetchToDoLists()
        .flatMap(new Func1<List<BcxToDoList>, Observable<BcxToDoList>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<BcxToDoList> call(List<BcxToDoList> bcxToDoLists) {
                return Observable.from(bcxToDoLists);
            }
        })
        .flatMap(new Func1<BcxToDoList, Observable<List<BcxToDo>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<List<BcxToDo>> call(BcxToDoList bcxToDoList) {
                return bcxClient
                        .fetchToDos(bcxToDoList.bucket.id);
                        .map(new Func1<List<BcxToDo>, BcxToDoList>() {
                            @Override
                            public BcxToDoList call(List<BcxToDo> bcxToDos) {
                                bcxToDoList.toDos.addAll(bcxToDos);
                                return bcxToDoList;
                            }
                        });
            }
        })
        .toList()
        .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: For each item in bcxToDoList, I have to call `fetchToDos` (with a parameter). How would I then add each bcxToDo to their relevant bcxToDoList?

Comment: I've edited my answer by adding request paramater. I've also removed splitting List<BcxToDo> to separate elements, but take a closer look on fetchToDos map - I'm mapping the response into current BcxToDoList but also adding the fetched List<BcxToDO>