# RxJava - Grouping by child data structure

Tags: android, rx-java

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140917/rxjava-combining-multiple-different-web-service-calls), I found out how to link child ToDo items with parent ToDo Lists (using nested web service calls). I learned some cool stuff, but then I realised I was making the wrong web service call!

In Basecamp, I can return all ToDo items for a Project in a single call complete with nested ToDo Lists. What I'd like to do is use RxJava to invert the structure and take care of the grouping.

Instead of:

- To Do 1

  - List 1
- To Do 2

  - List 1
- To Do 3

  - List 2
- To Do 4

  - List 2

I'd like:

- List 1

  - ToDo 1
  - ToDo 2
- List 2

  - ToDo 3
  - ToDo 4

Here's a cut down version of my ToDo List class:

```
public class BcxToDoList {
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public List<BcxToDo> toDos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And here's the ToDo List class:

```
public class BcxToDo {
    public String id;

    public String listId;

    public String content;

    public BcxToDoList toDoList;
}
```

I'd like to return a list of BcxToDoLists (`List<BcxToDoList>`) that have the grouped `toDos`.

Here's the code I have written so far:

```
bcxClient
  .fetchToDos( SomeProjectId )
  .flatMap(new Func1<List<BcxToDo>, Observable<BcxToDo>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<BcxToDo> call(List<BcxToDo> bcxToDos) {
      return Observable.from(bcxToDos);
    }
  })
  .groupBy(new Func1<BcxToDo, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(BcxToDo bcxToDo) {
      return bcxToDo.listId;
    }
  })
```

I tried grouping by bcxToDo.toDoList, but because this is an object I end up with one `BcxToDoList` per `BcxToDo`. Grouping by the listId creates the desired grouping, but now I need to translate my `GroupedObservable<String, BcxToDo>` to a `GroupedObservable<BcxToDoList, BcxToDo>`.

Even if I work out the above code, I'm not sure if this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bcxToDo.toDoList as a key in grouping, but remember to implement equals/hashCode methods in that class (IntelliJ can generate an implementation for you). In such case, you probably won't need BcxToDoList.toDos anymore. The groupBy output will be

```
GroupedObservable<BcxToDoList, BcxToDo>>
```