# Combine Retrofit Calls Using Rxjava

Tags: rx-java, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a list [ Chat List] containing all the chats that are stored on my phone.
I send this list to the server which in return sends me back a list of all the chats i do not have [ Missing Chats ].For each item in the Missing Chats list i want to make a call and fetch the user for that chat and after all that is done i want to combine the data and then display it to the user.
How can i go about doing this?

So far i tried using merge but that was resulting in the result of each merged observable arriving at different times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJava - Combining multiple/different web service calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140917/rxjava-combining-multiple-different-web-service-calls)

Comment: Not an actual answer, but have a loot at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214073/rxjava-instead-of-asynctask-pros-and-cons/39215031#39215031

Comment: This exactly is what are you looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41820372/7045114